# How can I solve this seemingly unsolvable integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral that I do not know how to solve:

$$\int{\frac{\sqrt{r^2 - y^2}}{(y-h)\sqrt{r^2 - y^2+(y-h)^2}}}\ dy.$$

I tried to use wolfram alpha, but it couldn't do it. Said "standard computation time exceeded". Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: Wolfram can solve it. I think your computer is just slow. It involves elliptic integrals, so there is no nice solution.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: WolframAlpha runs remotely, therefore the speed of the user's computer does not matter.

Comment: I tried it on wolfram. it's able to solve it, and there's no definite solution.

Comment: it gives an elliptic integral if i read your integral correct

Comment: do you really need the indefinite integral?

Comment: @HexaFlexagon So, it's unsolvable? What if put numerical constants instead of h and r? Would that make it any simpler?

Comment: @tired No, I actually need it from 0 to r, and another -r to 0 with the same integrand. If it makes it any simpler.

Comment: good lord:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5BSqrt%5Br%5E2-y%5E2%5D%2F(Sqrt%5B(y-h)%5E2%2Br%5E2-y%5E2%5D(y-h)),y%5D

Comment: at least the endresult will look nices

Comment: btw: the integral is not unsolvable...in fact there is a well known (but by no means simple!) procedure to bring this kind of integrals into acanonical form which might be expressed in terms of the three elliptic integrals plus elementary garbage

Comment: @tired This was just one side of $F=ma$ I was planning to solve the differential equation for $h(t)$. LOL.

Comment: @Anonymous Good luck, my friend!

Comment: interestingly the reduction to elliptic integrals is not too difficult in this case. the key step is to first apply a trigonometric sub and then recognizing ($a,b$ are parameters easily expressend in terms of $h,r$). Now you can split the integrand: whereas the first part can be expressed in terms of ellipitic1 and e2 only, the second form is almost in the form of e3 (up to well known trig manipulations) . 

$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{(1-b\sin(\phi))\sqrt{1-a \sin(\phi)}}=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(1-b^2\sin{\phi}^2)/b^2+1-1/b^2}{(1-b\sin(\phi))\sqrt{1-a \sin(\phi)}}
$$

Comment: @tired Thanks. I was able to solve the problem without this complicated integral. I used this theorem known as "Gauss's flux theorem for gravity". Interestingly the solution to the differential equation was quite simple. Thanks anyway.